# Testing revoke certificates in NPS server

Tags: windows, active-directory, certificate, radius, nps

I am testing a NPS server in Windows Server 2022, with PEAP (with certificates), the setup is:

- Windows Server 2022 --> AD DS (test.lab), AD CS, NPS
- Windows 10 --> Joined to domain

Certs in Windows Server 2022:

[certs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4ejJ.png)

NPS configuration:

[nps_eap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ4Mt.png)

Result:

[test_connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Krn3j.png)

The connection is succesfull, but now, I am trying to revoke the certificate for reject the connection but I dont know how are following steps... I have tried to revoke the certificate with Certificate Authority, but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To enable revocation check, please try the following:**

- Administrators must enable the ***RootCertificateNameToAccept*** parameter and set a registry key to enable functionality.
- To enable CRL (***Certification revocation List***) for IKEv2 VPN connections,
- Open a PowerShell window and below commands:

```cs
_$Thumbprint = ‘Root CA Certificate Thumbprint’_
_$RootCACert = (Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\root | Where-Object {$_.Thumbprint -eq $Thumbprint})_
_Set-VpnAuthProtocol -RootCertificateNameToAccept $RootCACert -PassThru_
```

```cs
_New-ItemProperty -Path ‘HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RemoteAccess\Parameters\Ikev2\’ -Name CertAuthFlags -PropertyTYpe DWORD -Value ‘4’ -Force_
```

```cs
_Restart-Service RemoteAccess -PassThru_
```

**Revoking certificates**

- The administrator must first revoke the certificate on the issuing CA.

Open a elevated command window and enter the below commands:

```cs
_certutil -urlcache * delete_
_certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now_
```

- If the above solution doesn't work, please try the following steps:

***Click start -> Administrative Tools -> Click Certification Authority -> Expand your CA -> Click the Issued Certificates folder -> Select issues certificates -> Click All Tasks -> click Revoke Certificate -> In the Certificate Revocation dialog box -> select Cease of Operation -> click OK***

**References :**

[certificate revocation | Richard M. Hicks Consulting, Inc. (richardhicks.com)](https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/tag/certificate-revocation/).

[How to Decommission a Windows Enterprise Certification Authority and How to Remove All Related Objects - TechNet Articles - United States (English) - TechNet Wiki (microsoft.com)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3527.how-to-decommission-a-windows-enterprise-certification-authority-and-how-to-remove-all-related-objects.aspx#Step_1_Revoke_all_active_certificates_that_are_issued_by_the_enterprise_CA).